# Javascript functions with objects-like properties

Tags: javascript, function

Is there anything wrong having javascript functions objects-like properties?

```
function foo(prop) { return foo[prop] }
foo.faa = 'blah';
foo.fee = 'bleh';
```

In my real case, I'm using as a status message:

(I couldn't paste my function here as S.O. said it was too much code, but [it can be found here](http://hastebin.com/akuxogacen.cs)).

So I can use like this:

`if (candidateStatus(candidate) === candidateStatus.ELECTED) {...}`

Comment: IMO this is a great way for dealing with validators and Enum type checking.

Comment: Functions are also objects. Just so you know, jQuery's `$` is actually a function. You can call it like `$('.selector')` but also hosts "static" functions like `$.each` and `$.ajax`.

Comment: You can read about object-oriented JavaScript programming at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript if you get bored:)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is nothing wrong with that. Functions (like almost everything else) in Javascript are objects, and can be treated as such.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong this will act like function [object like] properties

```
function foo(prop) { return foo[prop] }
foo.faa = 'blah';
foo.fee = 'bleh';

 // Is same as 

function foo(prop) { 
   this.faa = 'blan';  
   this.fee = 'bleh';
   return foo[prop];   // or we can write foo.prop
 }  
 var newFun = new foo();
  console.log(newFun['faa']);  // blan
```

Case this without  return statement

```
function foo() { 
   this.faa = 'blan';  
   this.fee = 'bleh';
 }  
 var newFun = new foo();
  console.log(newFoo.faa);  // blan
```

Comment: Sorry for the typos I am answering from the mobile App.  I have updated the answer it will work now